# How to run section of JavaScript code for certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript

How would I run the `document.getElementById("myLinkID").onclick = '';` part of the following code for 10 seconds? The Javascript runs a CSS animation which lasts 10 seconds and I don't want the code to run again until the animation has finished. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function myFuction() {

  var myVar = document.getElementById('myDivID');

  if (myVar.style.display === 'none') {
    myVar.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('myLinkID').onclick = '';
  }

  else {
    myVar.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

I have tried the following but it just freezes.

```
function myFunction() {

  var myVar = document.getElementById('myDivID');
  var myVar2 = true;

  while (myVar2 ) {
    document.getElementById('myLinkID').onclick = '';
  }

  setTimeout(function myFunction() {
    myVar2 = false;
  }, 10000);

  if (myVar.style.display === 'none') {
    myVar.style.display = 'block';

  } else {
    myVar.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Update fixed:

```
function myFuction() {

  var myVar = document.getElementById('myDivID');

  setTimeout(function() {
    myVar.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('myLinkID').onclick = myFunction;
  }, 10000);

  if (myVar.style.display === 'none') {
    myVar.style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('myLinkID').onclick = '';
  }

  else {
    myVar.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to run `document.getElementById("myLinkID").onclick = '';` in a loop. After you set `onclick` to an empty string, it will not do anything until you change it again. So run that statement one time, then set a timeout for 10 seconds to restore the `onclick` handler once the animation is finished.

Answer (score -1):

try the webkitAnimationEnd event to determine if this function is executed